# Nodejs redis method BLPOP blocks the event-loop

Tags: node.js, redis

I use the library node-redis: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis

```
let client = redis.createClient();
let blpopAsync = util.promisify(client.blpop).bind(client);
let rpushAsync = util.promisify(client.rpush).bind(client);

async function consume() {
    let data = await blpopAsync('queue', 0); // the program is blocked at here
}

async function otherLongRunningTasks() {
    // call some redis method
    await rpushAsync('queue', data);
}
```

I expect that method blpopAsync will be blocked until a element is popped. And in this time, event loop will run other async functions. However, my program is blocked at **await blpopAsync** forever.

Could you tell me how to use this function correctly to not block event-loop?

---

I find that blpop blocks other non-blocking methods of redis client, so other functions which use redis will wait forever. The event loop is still running.

Answer (score 1):

As @AnonyMouze mentioned, doing `client.duplicate().blpop(...)` is the trick to freeing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

i currently cannot comment so i will have to post it here. blpop will block when there is no data. Another thing to consider is the Redis's version . blpop behave differently between versions. You can refer to redis documentation .

Comment: Thank for your reply. I have just updated my question.

Comment: You can use client.duplicate()  to allow other to use the connection while blpop block and set timeout for blpop and handle accordingly.